# You chose to apply option ROM placement feature, while you knew it as risky

Tags: bios, rom

What does the `Option ROM Placement` in the bios do?

[image: bios]

I found a [manual referencing this option](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/374181/Gigabyte-Ga-2cewh.html?page=60) but it is also not helpful:

[image]

Comment: Option ROM is firmware called by the BIOS.  These are configurations options for that feature.

Comment: Looks like a poor translation job from a foreign manufacturer, quite common in my experience unless you dish out $150 or more on a MoBo. Maybe **[this](https://www.bootix.com/support/concepts_whitepapers/option_rom_en.html)** can help with figuring out what it is exactly

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - want to post that as the answer?